# Has anyone successfully installed the Open Source version WikiHow without major bugs?

Tags: php, debugging, open-source, wiki, mediawiki

I am working on trying to install and customize the OSS version of WikiHow (built on Mediawiki.) I am having a devil of a time getting even the basic feature set to work. The code is available here..

http://www.wikihow.com/x/wikihow-source-code.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Why not just install MediaWiki directly?

If you have an old PC lying around, than making a dedicated MediaWiki web appliance couldn't be easier.

[Turnkey Linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) offers a [MediaWiki](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/mediawiki) appliance. Pop in the CD, hit enter, and the installer will wipe your hard drive, install Ubuntu+MediaWiki and configure everything in a single keystroke.

I've used this before and its by far the most painless way of setting up a wiki that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, Andrew Fickert is the only person to date I know of one person who has succeeded besides WikiHow themselves.

As the installation instructions say, it requires:

- Web server with PHP 5.x or higher.
- A MySQL server, 4.0.14 or higher OR a Postgres server, 8.1 or higher

Once the server setup and the source code is download (from http://src.wikihow.com/), Gordon Joly says to add these lines to finish the installation:

```
require_once(‘extensions/wikihow/WikiHow.php’);
require_once(‘extensions/wikihow/FeaturedArticles.php’);
require_once(‘extensions/wikihow/Request.php’);
require_once(‘extensions/Postcomment/SpecialPostcomment.php’);
require_once(‘includes/SkinTemplate.php’);
require_once(’extensions/wikihow/FeaturedArticles.php’);
require_once(’extensions/wikihow/Request.php’);
require_once(’extentions/wikihow/PatrolHelper.php’);
```

to `WikiHowSkin.php`.

You will then find the “Patrol helper" is missing. Andy Roberts advised you will find it is included in the distribution at this location:

src.wikihow.com/wiki19/extensions/wikihow/PatrolHelper.php (Dead Link)

The code is known to be filled with bug and even with this great advice I suspect you will find this a challenge.

You can read more: http://distributedresearch.net/blog/2007/11/13/wikihow-how-to-install-wikihow-mediawiki-software#ixzz3P9uzti8H